# c++ source code organization for free functions

Tags: c++

I want to start to prefer free (non-member) functions over member functions - following this article http://www.drdobbs.com/184401197

I am used to organize my C++ classes in that way, that I have `ClassName.h` for the declaration and a `ClassName.C` for the implementation.

```
ClassName.h :

struct ClassName { 
    ClassName();
    void setData( unsigned data );
};
```

and the implementation is then

```
ClassName.C :

#include "ClassName.h"

ClassName::ClassName() { dosomething(); };
void setData( unsigned data ) { dootherthings(); };
```

So how do I organize my code when I want have a free function `adjustClassData()` ?
I also want to put this function into namespace.

Assuming `ClassName` is in `namespace foo`, then I would put the free function into `namespace foo` as well:

```
namespace foo {
    void adjustClassData( ClassName & inObj );
}
```

I am looking for the aspects of `namespace` and suggestions for file names.

I am looking for some best-practices - as there is no C++ rule in the standard prescribing the file organization.

Comment: Using `.c` as the file extension could cause trouble. For instance, _MSVC_ will compile it as C instead of C++.

Comment: That is a great article.

Comment: One (important) note: The `class` methods are responsible for maintaining the class invariants, the free-functions should only be helpers that use those methods to achieve more coarse-grained tasks.

Comment: @K-ballo: He used .C, not .c. You're right that Windows won't discriminate, meaning MSVC will cause problems. But other systems will discriminate, and there are projects out there that use .C/.c to distinguish C++ and C code.

Comment: @CarstenGreiner: There's really nothing for anyone to add about the "aspects of namespace" to what you've already got. Anything that's part of the public interface should be in the same namespace as the class. You may want to read up on how ADL works, but if you follow the rule you suggested, and don't do anything too tricky, it's going to do what you want. So the filenames are really the only issue.

Comment: @K-ballo & abarnert You point out something I missed out: I am all the time working an AIX and/or Linux and therefore the capital C extension does not cause problems (no Windows, always using compiler g++ or xlC (on AIX))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could put the free functions that deal with a particular class in the class header and implementation file if there are not too many.

Otherwise, come up with a naming convention and put them in a separate header and implementation file (e.g ClassNameFunctions.h/.cpp).

Comment: +1, but one minor suggestion: Even if there are enough functions to warrant a ClassNameFunctions.cpp for their definitions, I'd still put the declarations in ClassName.h instead of ClassNameFunctions.h. Or, alternatively, include ClassNameFunctions.h in ClassName.h. Because you normally expect to be able to get the full public interface of ClassName by including just ClassName.h.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to replace member functions with free functions, I'm assuming these free functions are tightly related to the class in question. In which case, they shouldn't be public. I'd go with anonymous inner namespaces:

```
//myclass.h
namespace myNamespace
{
   class MyClass
   { 
      void foo();
   };
}

//myclass.cpp
#include "myclass.h"
namespace myNamespace
{
   namespace
   {
      void helper() {};
   }
   void MyClass::foo()
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: I think he's suggesting that he wants to move the public interface from member functions to free functions (since that's what the cited article is about), which means this isn't relevant.

Answer (score 2):

i suggest to put the declaration of the free functions in a seperate header, as they are not part of the class itself, however i would put all in the same namespace.

```
//Bar.h
namespace foo{
class Bar{}
}
```

In the header where declaring the free functions i would use forward declaration for the class itself.

```
//BarHelper.hpp
namespace foo{
class Bar;
void somefunc(&Bar);
}
```

Implementation as usual in seperate files.

Right now i am crawling through tons of header files where declaration and definition of often several classes and free functions are mixed. It is a real pain.

So KISS ;)